# Are Flippase Recognition Target sites read through during transcription?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I believe it is quite straight forward, but if i have a FRT site following the last exon of a gene (with the stop codon removed), would the transcription factors read through the FRT site and transcribe whatever follows it, or would transcription be halted?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. One general piece of advice in communication is always to define acronyms and avoid using them in titles of questions unless they are very well known (DNA etc.). This will increase the likelihood of people looking at and understanding your question and answering it. You can edit your question. Perhaps shorten the title removing what comes after "or" (that can go in the body) and putting in the question mark.

Comment: @David thank you! And appreciate the advice, made the changes as well!